# error when trying to install rar package - php centos

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, php, debian, rar

```
building in /tmp/pear/temp/rar
running: phpize
sh: phpize: command not found
rolling back 388 file operations
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

getting this error when trying to install the RAR package for php using the command "pecl -v install rar"

what does that means and how can i fix it ? i'm a linux newbie.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install php-devel as well. Since you are using CentOS :

```
yum install php-devel
```

will do the trick

Comment: Already tried. Doesn't work. Error: -bash: yum: command not found

Comment: there is no yum installed ? then there must be something really really wrong with your system. Are you sure it is CentOS ?

Comment: Sorry my bad, i just checked again and i'm on Debian 6.0 Squeeze. I just bought this dedicated server so i'm a bit confused.

Comment: then the command is apt-get install php-dev or apt-get install php5-dev depends on your php version.

Comment: this is what i am getting now, after running pecl -v install rar .....  configure: error: in `/var/tmp/pear-build-root/rar-3.0.1':
configure: error: C++ preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check
See `config.log' for more details
rolling back 388 file operations
ERROR: `/tmp/pear/temp/rar/configure' failed

Comment: it looks like you don't have gcc and/or gcc++ installed either so you can manually compile software like you are trying to do.